# Net Core IgnoreQueryFilters custom implementation

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create my own implementation of Net Core's IgnoreQueryFilters() method.
This because I have to perform some extra operations when Ignoring the filters.

I found the original implementation of it in efcores github project:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs

My take on it is as follows. Currently, the only difference is the name of the method and class:

```
public static class SoftDeleteExtensions
{

    internal static readonly MethodInfo IgnoreQueryFiltersMethodInfo = typeof(SoftDeleteExtensions).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethod(nameof(IncludeDeleted))!;

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeDeleted<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source) where TEntity : class
    {
        if (!(source.Provider is EntityQueryProvider))
        {
            return source;
        }
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(Expression.Call(null, IgnoreQueryFiltersMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntity)), source.Expression));
    }

}
```

When running the following code, it runs fine:

```
using EnevoLeadsContext context = new EnevoLeadsContext();
List<Mission> missions = context.Missions.IgnoreQueryFilters().OrderBy(m => m.Id).Take(500).ToList();
```

However, when using my own extension:

```
using EnevoLeadsContext context = new EnevoLeadsContext();
List<Mission> missions = context.Missions.IncludeDeleted().OrderBy(m => m.Id).Take(500).ToList();
```

I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=The
> LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(m => !(m.Deleted))
> .IncludeDeleted()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation
> explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable',
> 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

What is it that I'm missing?

Comment: What you have did - just injected new UNKNOWN for EF Core method into Expression Tree. For sure it throws exception.  From my knowledge of LINQ translation, it is not possible to implement such translation in reasonable time - too complicated and probably needs EF Core sources modification.

Comment: The original method is used by EFCore at least here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/87f933f70a33015d834cc7f2118991fcccc5db9c/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/QueryableMethodNormalizingExpressionVisitor.cs#L211
That code sets `_queryCompilationContext.IgnoreQueryFilters = true`, which is later used here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/231565fb03ea76fbb9b7f7a5744a4246e4641e74/src/EFCore/Query/Internal/NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.cs#L1620
So it seems you can't disable the filters selectively, maybe instead try re-adding them i.e. `query.IgnoreQueryFilters().ThenAddSomeBack()`